# PLSQL cycle formed in methods

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In a package I have procedures which call other procedures and are forming cycle and getting "PLS-00313: 'Checklist' not declared in this scope" error.

```
Checklist procedure -> Task method.
Task method -> Step Checklist method.
Step Checklist method -> Checklist method.
```

How to resolve this? Does plsql have something like prototypes of c++?

Comment: I don't know about *prototypes*. Did you put all those procedures into package specification? If not, do so and try again.

Comment: Why do you switch between *"procedure"* and *"method"*? Does the inconsistency in terminology have any relevance to the architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there are private procedures or functions in your package that you want to call.

private functions and procedures are those that are not defined in the specification

Alternative 1:
the procedure that is called is always at the top of the package body or of the top of the caller.

e.g.: 
Checklist is public

```
create OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypck AS 
  procedure Checklist procedure;
  procedure main;
end;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypck AS 

  -- private procedures

  procedure Step Checklist is ... -- should be here because is called from  Task method, calls public checklist procedure

  procedure Task is ... -- should be here,because it calls private Step Checklist procedure and is called from  Checklist

 -- public procedures

  procedure Checklist is ... -- calls private Task procedure

  procedure main is ... -- calls public Checklist procedure

END mypck; 
/
```

Alternative 2:
Use forward declaration to make all private procedures visible in package body by entering the signature for the entire body

```
create OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypck AS 
  procedure main;
end;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypck AS 

  -- forward declaration here of all private signature

  procedure Task ;
  procedure Step Checklist;
  procedure Checklist;

  -- define implementation of private procedures

  -- use in order you want to use it
  procedure Step Checklist is ... -- calls private Checklist procedure 

  procedure Task is ...  -- calls private Step Checklist procedure

  procedure Checklist is ...  -- calls private Task procedure


  -- public procedure

  procedure main is -- calls private Checklist procedure

END mypck; 
/
```

Comment: I have edited your code to clarify the second implementation. The point of forward declaration is that all the routines remain private. We declare the signatures in any order and then define the procedures in any order (although it's good practice to use the same order as the forward declaration).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

The first approach is to "fix" the scope error by including `checklist()` in the package specification (which makes it public and so can be referenced by any  procedure defined in the body) or by using forward declaration to define procedures at the top of the package body (which allows subsequent procedures to reference them regardless of the order in which the procedures are written). [These are the solutions given by @hotfix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61225270/146325).

However, there is a problem with this approach: your code executes a recursive loop like this

```
Checklist -> Task -> Step Checklist -> Checklist
```

So you must code something in either `checklist()` or `step checklist()` which breaks the cycle and unwinds the code. The need to do this is a red flag, suggesting there is something awry in your design.

Hence the second approach is to step back and consider whether there's another way to implement your business logic without the cyclic dependency. Cyclic dependencies are a bad thing in software architecture and should be avoided whenever possible. The usual solution is to isolate the common dependency - in this case the operation which both  `checklist()` and `step checklist()` need to execute - and extract it into a new subroutine. Then change both procedures to call the new procedure.

This can be easy or hard to achieve, depending on the nature of the common reliance: it will be easier to fix a pure piece of code and harder to fix a recursion in the underlying data model. Either way it's worth taking the time to remove the cyclic dependency. Acyclic dependency graphs are less brittle, more comprehensible and easier to maintain.